# use of return on in jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a basic plugin in jquery. The plugin works fine even without using return in plugin but on jquery site they are using return to create a plugin. So I just want to know what is the need of return in plugin. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nm93a/)

```
$.fn.abc= function(options){    
     var settings = $.extend({
    // These are the defaults.
    width: "50px",
    borderLeft: "solid 1px #cecece"
    }, options );

    this.width(150)

    this.find('ul').each(function(i,elem){
        console.log(elem)       
        $(elem).css({width:settings.width})

    })      

}
```

Comment: you dont need to return anything, in jquery they return the object itself for chaining purposes. eg: `.stop().css().show()`

Comment: That's really up to the purpose of your function. If you need to do something with the value it produces than you may want to return it. If it doesn't produce any value or you don't need that for anything not returning anything is also ok.

Comment: You really don't need to add the [tag:jsfiddle] tag on questions that aren't actually *about JSFiddle*, @Tripp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return is used for chaining, the plugin you created need not return anything, but you might want to create two plugins which will be chained together, You are not returning anything so,

`$('div').abc().css("background":"red");`

wouldn't work..

coming to your question,

```
var el= this.find('ul').each(function(i,elem){
    console.log(elem)       
    $(elem).css({width:settings.width})

});
return el;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nm93a/2/

this way I can return all element rather than doing

```
 return this.find('ul').each(function(i,elem){
            console.log(elem)       
            $(elem).css({width:settings.width})

        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nm93a/1/

> both of these codes work similarly, the advantage of using the jquery
>   approach is  writing less code

, these small things make jquery a light weight library

Comment: I know about chaining, But my question is why we need to use return with each function instead we can return this at end of the funtion

Comment: both are similar, when you return with each you are writing less code instead of writing separate statement for returning all elements.

Comment: edited my code hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

It's to use chaining, without the return you couldn't do stuff like:

```
$('.element').hide().show().css({width:200}).animate({height:100}),
```

instead you would have to rewrite the selector each time

```
$('.element').hide();
$('.element').show();
$('.element').css({width:200});
$('.element').animate({height:100});
```

Comment: Excellent answer, Jonas. I took the liberty of changing "concatenation" to "chaining" since that's the term commonly used for this.

Comment: No problems, thanks for the correction

Comment: Glad to help. I really like the way you illustrated the concept with your examples.

Comment: But my question is why we need to use return with each function instead we can return this at end of the funtion

Comment: No, your question is: "So I just want to know what is the need of return in plugin.". Anyway, I can't think of a big difference between returning it each time or returning a collection of jQuery elements. Actually, since your plugin is most likely to get a collection of elements, I think returning a collection as well is the way to go.

Comment: No there is no return each time instead the result after executing each loop is returned, it is returning a collection.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` is used to return a value when the function is done...  Say I had a very basic JavaScript function:

```
addNums = function(value1, value2){
  return value1 + value2;
}
```

Then I were to do something like:

```
alert( addNums(4, 4) );
```

This would return `8` because:

```
return value1 + value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean something like

```
$.fn.plugin = function() {
    var settings = $.extend({
        width: '50'
    }, options);

    // return statement here?
    return this.find('ul').each(function(i, el){
        console.log(el);
    })
}
```

If so, by adding `return`, you allow chaining. It returns the jQuery object (with context) that is passed to the method (which can further be passed).